# How to configure VSTS GIT Repository with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: azure-devops, tortoisesvn

Would like to use VSTS Git repository with TortoiseSVN or any other open source client for source control. I will not going to use VS SDK for my project files as all of them are static HTML files but I really want to push files to Git on VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is the tool for SVN (not Git) client source control system.

It's ok use any GUIs to connect with VSTS git repo instead of using VS.

Such as you can use TortoiseGit, SourceTree etc to connect with VSTS git repo.